# It always displays an error while uploading a file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php) where the user adds a table row and it will show a file input in the row. Now the problem I have is that if you select a file using the input and click on "Upload", it always states that there is an error while uploading the file, this happens for any file.

I have set the permissions for the file to be able to read and write but it still states there is an error while uploading a file. If anyone has used MAx's AJAX file uploader and has had this problem before but then fixed it then can I ask how you have solved this problem. If not then is there other ways I solve this problem so that it stops displaying an error message for perfectly legitimate file uploading and instead display file uploaded successful message.

When I tested the same code in this link which uses a different server: [[er5325.aisites.com/scripts/stack/test.html](http://er5325.aisites.com/scripts/stack/test.html)  , then it doesn't display there is an error message when a legitimate file  is uploaded.

I am using the university's server which is helios.hud.ac.uk

Below is the code of the file input and the functions to stop and start uploading:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var sourceForm; 

    function insertQuestion(form) {   

        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>"); 


       var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='startUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
        "<p class='imagef1_upload_process' align='center'>Loading...<br/><img src='Images/loader.gif' /><br/></p><p class='imagef1_upload_form' align='center'><br/><label>" + 
        "File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><label>" + 
        "(jpg, jpeg, pjpeg, gif, png, tif)</label><br/><br/><label>" + 
        "<input type='submit' name='submitBtn' class='sbtn' value='Upload' /></label>" +
        "</p> <iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='wclassth:0;height:0;border:0px;solclass #fff;'></iframe></form>");

        $image.append($fileImage);

        $tr.append($image);  
        $tbody.append($tr); 

    }

   function startUpload(imageuploadform){
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceForm = imageuploadform;
      return true;
}

    function stopUpload(success){
          var result = '';
          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }
          $(sourceForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden');
          $(sourceForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').html(result + '<label>File: <input name="fileImage" type="file"/><\/label><br/><label>(jpg, jpeg, pjpeg, gif, png, tif)</label><br/><br/><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>');
          $(sourceForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');     
          return true;   
    }
    </script>
```

Below is the upload page (imageupload.php) where it uploads the files:

```
<?php
   // Edit upload location here
   $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

   $result = 0;

   $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);

   if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
   }

   sleep(1);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>);</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [It always states there is an error while uploading a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065320/it-always-states-there-is-an-error-while-uploading-a-file)

Comment: DELETE this since you created it a second time.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have write rights in $destination_path. Also, what If somebody upload a evil.php file? it sounds like he can overwrite your script or upload any evil file. Perhaps you sould move the files to a path outside of the www tree.

Comment: I will do this but I am taking it one step at a time, first thing is trying to get the uploading file working. So are you saying set write permissions for the imageupload.php? (this is where the $destination_path is stored in.

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow your code, but perhaps function startUpload(source_form) is not doing what you want it to do. You use the same name for the local variable than a global variable, then write something like  sourceForm = source_form; that will not have any effect. Perhaps you can find a way to avoid global variables, or rename the local variable to something different.

```
function startUpload(imageuploadform){
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceForm = imageuploadform;
      return true;
}
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with the error, but will make your code less weird.

Have you tested your script can write files where you are tryiing? have you acces to the log of the server to check related errors?

Comment: I changed code, hasn't fixed the error but you are right makes it look less wierd, I updated code above to include the change of variable